# How to see the rect nodes without [every node/.style={draw}]

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-node, node-connections, tikz-path

In the code below if we add `[every node/.style={draw}]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}` then we see the rectangular nodes. But I do not like this as I do not want to add this to every node in my tikzpicture especially if I wanna add more nodes later on. Instead I like to put it in the path properties such as `\path[draw, SOME UNKNOWN ADDITIONAL PATH PROPERTY TO DRAW THE RECT NODES, shape=rectangle]`. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw, shape=rectangle]
(0,0) node(a1){} (1,0) node(a2){}
(1,1) node(a3){} (0,1) node(a4){};
\filldraw[fill=yellow!80!black] (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) -- (a4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzset{d/.style=draw, n/.style={draw=none}}` This can save some key stroke if you intensively switch between drawing vs not drawing nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is we can add `every node/.style={draw}` as a path property instead of putting it after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. So the answer is as below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[every node/.style={draw},draw, shape=rectangle]
(0,0) node(a1){} (1,0) node(a2){}
(1,1) node(a3){} (0,1) node(a4){};
\filldraw[fill=yellow!80!black] (a1) -- (a2) -- (a3) -- (a4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```